# C# Implement inherited abstract member

Tags: c#

I am trying to inherit abstract members from a derived class and it is not working.
I have set the class as abstract such as

Now my main program says the same thing about the CalculateWeeklyPay()  and I shouldn't need it in my main class.  How can I fix that?

Comment: How are you declaring your `Hourly` entity? If it's cast as an Employee, it will try to use the inherited method and not the overridden one.

Comment: Could you give your full abstract class definition?

Comment: You need to [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) absract members

Comment: After seeing more of the code I have posted an answer that hopefully works for you below, my comment above does not apply to your problem.

Comment: Why did you remove your code?

Answer (score 3):

```
// Pay method
public double CalculateWeeklyPay(double Hours, double Wage)
{
    return Hours * Wage;
}
```

The parameter list to `CalculateWeeklyPay` is hiding the class members `Hours` and `Wage`.  I suspect you want this instead:

```
// Pay method
public double CalculateWeeklyPay()
{
    return Hours * Wage;
}
```

In fact, I would go a step further and make it a read-only property instead:

```
// Pay method
public double WeeklyPay
{
    get { return Hours * Wage; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 output += "\n\t   Weekly Pay:\t" + CalculateWeeklyPay().ToString("C2");
```

You define `public double CalculateWeeklyPay(double Hours, double Wage)`,but in this function there are not two double number.It is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. He's not calling it with 2 number inputs I expect is what you should mean..

Answer (score 1):

```
public override double CalculateWeeklyPay(){...}
```

abstract is like virtual except that a derived class must either override it or else must become abstract itself.

Comment: I have fixed the error in my Hourly class but it then did the same thing for my program class.  I don't think I need to put that same method in my program class

Answer (score 0):

`output += "\n\t   Weekly Pay:\t" + CalculateWeeklyPay().ToString("C2");`

CalculateWeeklyPay is expecting 2 arguments: Wage and Hours. Remove those arguments from the definition and it will work:

```
public override double CalculateWeeklyPay()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Once I removed the definitions I get a warning that says
Employee.Hourly.CalculateWeeklyPay()' hides inherited member 'Employee.Employee.CalculateWeeklyPay()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
as well as having the 2 errors still

Comment: You probably get a warning because you have it declared in your abstract class as well - use the override operator. I've updated the answer to match.

Comment: How do you override it?
The error says
Type 'Employee.Employee' already defines a member called 'CalculateWeeklyPay' with the same parameter types